# Where can I find a theme that has a big banner

Tags: themes

Where can I find a theme that has a big custom banner  like this for each article:

http://greyenlightenment.com/real-estate-palo-alto-vs-everywhere-else/

but also a grid homepage layout?  I want each post on the home page to be arranged like a grid of uniform height and width ..like these https://colorlib.com/wp/masonry-grid-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free theme from Wordpress themes repository with your required features: https://wordpress.org/themes/palm-beach/

This [link](https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/grid-layout+custom-background+featured-image-header+blog/) filters all of the themes with custom banner/featured image banner on blog posts and have a grid layout and all of these are hosted on Wordpress repository to use freely!

You can find a lot of premium themes with your required features available on market places like [themeforest](https://themeforest.net), [creativemarket](https://creativemarket.com/) etc...